# Set range only produces first row of data

Tags: excel, loops, range, with-statement, vba

I'm carrying out the function of looping through a folder and collecting a range of data accordingly from each workbook. My code is able to run but why is it only copy the first row of range selected.

> Range to be copied: I80:I83. Only copy I80

[image]

**Code is below**

```
Dim lastRow As Range, rng1 As Range, lastrow2 As Range, rng2 As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set rng1 = Worksheets(2).Range("I80:I83")
Set rng2 = Worksheets(2).Range("I1")

Set lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
lastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Columns.Count, rng1.Rows.Count) = rng1.Value


Set lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
lastrow2.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count, rng2.Columns.Count) = rng2.Value
End With
```

**Output of code**
[image]

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row and column resize is backwards.

```
lastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count) = rng1.Value
```

If your intention was to write 4 rows of data into 4 columns then you need to transpose the array.

```
lastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Columns.Count, rng1.Rows.Count) = application.transpose(rng1.Value)
```

You also might want to put multiple values into column A.

```
lastrow2.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count) = rng2.Value
```